# How to validate JSON-LD microdata agains schema.org's schema with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to validate a set of https://schema.org formatted JSON-LD files (100+) to make sure that they follow schema.org rules. But I'm having a hard time to find a working JS/PHP/Python library with an example.

The best I could find is https://github.com/chharvey/schemaorg-jsd, but it seems to be abandoned and never finds any issues with my files, even in obviously broken ones.

I would appreciate any help, link to the working Github repo, article, code sample.

Here is one file for example:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://moz.com/blog/best-free-seo-tools"
    },
    "headline": "The 60 Best Free SEO Tools [100% Free]",
    "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://moz.com/uploads/og_image/5d4b2923e22013.80121530.jpg",
        "height": 440,
        "width": 880
    },
    "datePublished": "2019-06-10T00:04:00-07:00",
    "dateModified": "2020-03-11T13:17:16-07:00",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Cyrus Shepard",
        "sameAs": [
            "https://moz.com/community/users/155620",
            "https://twitter.com/cyrusshepard"
        ]
    },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Moz",
        "url": "https://moz.com",
        "sameAs": [
            "https://twitter.com/moz",
            "https://www.facebook.com/moz/",
            "https://www.youtube.com/user/MozHQ",
            "https://www.linkedin.com/company/moz",
            "https://www.instagram.com/moz_hq/",
            "https://www.pinterest.com/mozhq/"
        ],
        "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://d2eeipcrcdle6.cloudfront.net/brand-guide/logos/moz_blue.png",
            "width": 134,
            "height": 39
        }
    },
    "description": "There are literally hundreds of free SEO tools out there, so we focused on only the best and most useful to add to your toolbox."
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think JSON Schema is what you're looking for, since there's multiple different ways you can construct a valid JSON-LD document; and it's not encoding a tree like JSON encodes, it's actually encoding a graph, and it's the graph that you want to validate.
Is something like https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool up your alley?

Comment: You are right, each part of the JSON-LD document is graph element, but each @type has its own list of fields and data types associated with them. That's what I wish to be able to validate. I basically need Google's Structured Data Testing Tool running locally reading JSON-LD files from a folder.

Comment: I think the "right" way to automate this would be generate an RDF graph from the JSON-LD document; then test that with something like RDF Shapes. But I'm not aware of a way to test schema.org data in particular.

However, if what is important is that the search engines are reading it correctly, maybe what you're looking for is a service to test that, such as Google Search Console or the aforementioned Structured Data Testing Tool.

Comment: @AlexanderErm Any luck finding solution ?  Please share.